# Is it bad to put expensive statements in static class attributes if class is instantiated often?

Tags: python, class, oop, static

I have a class with the following structure.

```
class MyClass:
    
    my_variable = pickle.load(open("my_file.p", "rb"))

    def __init__(self):
        .
        .
        .
```

I assume, `pickle.load()` is an expensive operation that is why I am wondering if it will get called every time I instantiate the class, or is it just once when the file is imported?

Comment: in the example you show it happens once at import time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All class attributes (`my_variable`, `__init__`, etc) are *defined* when the class is defined. Methods like `__init__` are *called* when the class is instantiated, but none of the class attributes are redefined at that point.

`pickle.load` will only be called once, when `MyClass` is first defined.

---

Basically, you can think of the `class` statement as being a declarative way of writing

```
def my_class_init(self):
    ...

namespace = {
    '__init__': my_class_init,
    'my_variable': pickle.load(...)
}

MyClass = type('MyClass', (), namespace)
```

with `pickle.load` only being called to define the `dict` bound to `namespace`.

Answer (score 0):

it will load one time when the class instance  is  created and this class attribute (my_variable) is shared among all the class instances, and any modification is shared among all. so it is one time operation.